# VBS Script not grabbing all AD groups

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

The following script was originally written to grab all the AD groups for a user (from a prompt) and export them to a txt file.  Doing some comparisons recently has revealed the script is not grabbing all the AD groups.  Any insight would be appreciated.

```
strInput = UserInput( "Enter the source user's AD username:" )
strInput2 = UserInput( "Enter folder path to save the output usergroups.txt file, ex. c:\temp:" )
strFile = strinput & ".txt"
Set ADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
DomainString = WSHNetwork.UserDomain
Set UserObj = GetObject("WinNT://" & DomainString & "/" & strInput)
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const ForAppending = 8

If objFSO.FileExists(strInput2 & strFile) Then
   Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strInput2)
Else
   Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strInput2 & strFile)
   'Wscript.Echo "Just created " & strDirectory & strFile
End If 

set objFile = nothing
set objFolder = nothing

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
(strInput2 & strFile, ForAppending, True)

For Each GroupObj In UserObj.Groups
    'wscript.echo GroupObj.Name
    objTextFile.WriteLine(GroupObj.Name)

Next

objTextFile.Close
wscript.echo "Completed.  The usergroups.txt file is saved to " & strInput2 & "."

Function UserInput( myPrompt )
' This function prompts the user for some input.
' When the script runs in CSCRIPT.EXE, StdIn is used,
' otherwise the VBScript InputBox( ) function is used.
' myPrompt is the the text used to prompt the user for input.
' The function returns the input typed either on StdIn or in InputBox( ).
' Written by Rob van der Woude
' http://www.robvanderwoude.com
    ' Check if the script runs in CSCRIPT.EXE
    If UCase( Right( WScript.FullName, 12 ) ) = "\CSCRIPT.EXE" Then
        ' If so, use StdIn and StdOut
        WScript.StdOut.Write myPrompt & " "
        UserInput = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
    Else
        ' If not, use InputBox( )
        UserInput = InputBox( myPrompt )
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Can you use powershell instead? Can do this with 1 line and are assured theres no problems. As to your issue, the Groups collection probably only contains groups the user is directly a member of, not recursive.

Comment: Thank you.  I just inherited the script and was looking into the "why".  I will research powershell and suggest it as a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

This might have something to do with it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321538

Why are you using the WinNT provider anyway? That's for an old-school NT domain. For Active Directory, you're better off using LDAP. Mind you, you can't look up an account directly with only the domain\username. You have to search the domain for accounts with sAMAccountName=username, then pull the memberOf attribute to see the groups the account is a member of.

Or just use PowerShell as Ashigore suggests.